# How to set tibble column types programmatically

Tags: r, tidyr, readxl

I have a tibble from reading a tall XLSX file using:

```
> file = readxl::read_xlsx(filename, "sheetname")
```

An toy example avoiding an actual XLSX file:

```
> file = tibble(
+     names = c("name1", "name2", "name3"),
+     values = c(TRUE, 1, "chr")
+ )
> file
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  names values
  <chr> <chr> 
1 name1 TRUE  
2 name2 1     
3 name3 chr
```

I want to convert it into this:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  name1 name2 name3
  <dbl> <lgl> <chr>
1     1 TRUE  chr
```

but because `pivot_wider()` determines that the values column is of type `<chr>`, `pivot_wider()` keeps that type for all widened columns.

```
> file %>% pivot_wider(names_from = names, values_from = values)
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  name1 name2 name3
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 TRUE  1     chr
```

This requires me to manually set each column type again. Is there another (automated) way? The format of this file is fixed, but the contents might change so I can't rely on hardcoded type setting. Ideally for me, we could do something like

```
readxl::read_xlsx(filename, "sheetname") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = column1, values_from = column2, col_types = NULL)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we wrap with `type.convert`, it would automatically change the type

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
file %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = names, values_from = values) %>% 
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE)
# A tibble: 1 x 3
#  name1 name2 name3
#  <lgl> <int> <chr>
#1 TRUE      1 chr
```

---

or use `deframe/as_tibble_row`, convert to `tibble`

```
library(tibble)
deframe(file) %>% 
   as_tibble_row %>% 
   type.convert(as.is = TRUE)
```

---

Another option is `data.table::transpose`

```
type.convert(data.table::transpose(file, make.names = 'names'), as.is = TRUE)
#  name1 name2 name3
#1  TRUE     1   chr
```

#### data

```
file <- structure(list(names = c("name1", "name2", "name3"), values = c("TRUE", 
"1", "chr")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```